# What is caller in Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In Bootstrap Modal option document, there are some sentence in bold type:

For example with `modal('show')`:

Manually opens a modal. **Returns to the caller before the modal has actually been shown** (i.e. before the shown.bs.modal event occurs).

Actually, I know it will be used to open modal. But part in bold above, what does it mean? And what is the caller?

Comment: Hi @Sanchez, whilst both are good, you have two questions here. Why not split them up into two separate questions which will allow us to answer more explicitly?

Comment: Thank you @Tom, i will pay attention.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** Any script ***call***ing another script is a caller. `call` is a generic name used in JavaScript for **"execute"**, also synonym with **"run"** or **"apply"**. The script making the call is `caller`. The script being called is `callee`.

---

`caller` is the script that calls the method (open/close). **Your script.**

*"Returns to the caller before [...]"* means you can use the returned result of this method to make any changes to the modal instance... *"before [...]"*, if you need to.

This is useful when you manually (in fact, programmatically) open/close modals, because you can trigger custom logic prior to the modal being shown/hidden.

Possible use cases (a few examples, the list is endless):

- hiding other modals (when you open a modal from another modal you want to close the opened one and show the current one after),
- when you only use one modal instance in your page and dynamically add content to it based on where the modal was called from
- when the contents of your modal need instantiation, often coupled with the dynamic contents method mentioned above.

Comment: @Sanchez, I've updated my answer with a more concise version of what **caller** refers to in the quoted context.

Comment: Ok, i see. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, Caller is the function, statement who is calling the 
**element.open('show')** in your case etc.
It is returning to caller before **shown.bs.modal event** occurs because 
**CSS transitions** need time to complete or some content to be added before 
actually shown.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Azeem Chauhan!